# Output JSON encoded array through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a single json encoded array set in an ajax call:

```
 $var = json_encode($_SESSION['pictures']);
```

I put this json encoded array in a var called "array"
When I alert the var array, I receive the following callback:

```
  ["http://linktoimage1", "http://linktoimage2"]
```

now I want to output the first value through a jquery call:

```
 $('#imgswap').attr('src', array[0]);
```

When I make this jquery call, I receive the value "[". If I change it to array[2], I receive "h". So he's giving me back characters instead of the complete values of the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your last line to this:

```
$('#imgswap').attr('src', JSON.parse(array[0]));
```

You need to parse your JSON. If you don't do that, you have a string, not an array.

Comment: is it also possible to parse the array totally, for example var array = JSON.parse($var);, so that I can use only $('#imgswap').attr('src', array[0]); ??

Comment: @Stefan: Yes. You can definitely do that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the json in order to make it an array otherwise its just a string

```
array = $.parseJSON(array);
$('#imgswap').attr('src', array[0]);
```

Also you can have jQuery.ajax parse it for you if you set the `dataType` to `json`

Comment: is it also possible to parse the array totally, for example var array = JSON.parse($var);, so that I can use only $('#imgswap').attr('src', array[0]); ??

Comment: @Musa: Didn't know JQ had a JSON method. I guess jQuery really does do everything...

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving your data as a string rather than as actual JSON. Are you using `dataType: text` in your AJAX call? If so, either omit that line or replace it with `dataType: json`.